# How to add shortcuts in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I want to create static shortcuts in my app, but since Jetpack Compose uses a SingleActivity architecture, although the shortcut option appears in my app, there is no response when clicked. How can I configure it so that the shortcuts lead to the desired paths?

My shortcuts.xml

```
<?xml version ="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shortcuts xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <shortcut android:shortcutId="search"
         android:enabled="true"
         android:shortcutShortLabel="@string/shortcut_search"
         android:icon="@drawable/ic_search">
         <intent
             android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
             android:targetPackage="tw.com.test.app"
             android:targetClass="tw.com.test.app.MainActivity"/>
     </shortcut>
</shortcuts>
```